# Getting X509 Certificate from Signed envelop data

Tags: ios, objective-c, openssl

I want to convert following Java code into iOS. Please help me out.

```
CMSSignedDataParser sp = new CMSSignedDataParser(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(), contents.getBuffer());

sp.getSignedContent().drain();

Store                   certStore = sp.getCertificates();
SignerInformationStore  signers = sp.getSignerInfos();

Collection              c = signers.getSigners();
Iterator                it = c.iterator();

while (it.hasNext())
{
    SignerInformation   signer = (SignerInformation)it.next();
    Collection          certCollection = certStore.getMatches(signer.getSID());

    Iterator        certIt = certCollection.iterator();
    X509CertificateHolder cert = (X509CertificateHolder)certIt.next();
    X509Certificate certificate = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider( "BC" ).getCertificate( cert );
}
```

Here in Java extracting X509 Certificate from Signed Info. How to achieve same thing in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Check out `CMSDecoder.h` in the Security.framework. That plus the openssl framework you get you started.

**WRONG**
The `Cryptographic Message Syntax` API is not public on iOS. I guess it's openssl all the way. Sorry!

Comment: It looks like the CMS API is public now:  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/CryptoMessageRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006264

Comment: It's public on MacOSX, but not on iOS.